# Failed to apply network settings, connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine

Tags: networking, python, bluetooth

After updating to Ubuntu 16.04, from 14 I am getting a

> Failed to apply network settings.

I found this https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/513 but I am running the latest version of Ubuntu. The suggestions I found from stack overflow do not seem related.

The full error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.UnicodeDecodeError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/DbusService.py", line 36, in wrapper
    return method(*args[1:], **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/mechanism/Network.py", line 63, in ReloadNetwork
    nc = NetConf.get_default()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py", line 219, in get_default
    obj = pickle.load(f) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the workaround from [ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/1574093)

The [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/blueman-project/blueman/pull/515.diff) for /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py is

```
diff --git a/blueman/main/NetConf.py b/blueman/main/NetConf.py
index 61f5a63..24268df 100644
--- a/blueman/main/NetConf.py
+++ b/blueman/main/NetConf.py
@@ -299,7 +299,7 @@ def get_default(cls):
         NetConf.default_inst = obj
         f.close()
         return obj
- except IOError:
+ except (IOError, UnicodeDecodeError):
         n = cls()
         try:
             n.store()
```

Comment: The patch wasn't working so I manually changed /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py on line 225.